# Usability testing of GNOME Shell?

Tags: gui-design, open-source

I've searched around the internet in vain for usability studies that would validate the controversial design of [GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Design).  Has anyone else had better luck or would know where to look?

Comment: @Midas That covers some of the GNOME applications, not the usage of GNOME Shell (the desktop interface).

Answer (score 1):

There is a study from 2014: [Usability Themes in Open Source Software](http://www.freedos.org/jhall/opensource-usability/opensource-usability.pdf) (PDF) which focuses on GNOME 3, and a follow up from 2016 here: [A Usability Study of GNOME](http://fossforce.com/2016/03/usability-study-gnome/).

Comment: From the first article: "the overall GNOME desktop was not part of the usability test".  Although it's good to see GNOME do studies on their applications, I'm more interested in studies about GNOME Shell (the overall desktop experience).